# Catching an exception within a map

Tags: scala, loops, dictionary, exception, scala-collections

What is the best way of handling exceptions while iterating over a loop in Scala?

For instance, if I had a `convert()` method that could throw an exception, I'd like to catch that exception, log it, and keep iterating.  Is there a "scala" way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like something like...

```
val points: Seq[Point] = ...
val convertedPoints: Seq[ConvertedPoint] = points.map(
   p => {
     try { p.convert() } 
     catch { case ex: Exception => logger.error("Could not convert", ex) }
})
```

You can't do the above code since it's not a direct mapping from one list to the other (you get back `Seq[Any]` as opposed to `Seq[ConvertedPoint]`).

Answer (score 17):

flatMap is probably what you're looking for, but the map function has logging side-effect and these side-effects may not  occur immediately if points were a view:

```
val convertedPoints = points.view.flatMap { p =>
  try { 
    Some(p.convert) 
  } catch {
    case e : Exception =>
    // Log error
    None
  }
}
println("Conversion complete")
println(convertedPoints.size + " were converted correctly")
```

This would print:

```
Conversion complete
[Error messages]
x were converted correctly
```

In your case, drop the view and you're probably fine. :)

To make the conversion a pure function (no side-effects), you'd probably use Either. Although I don't think it's worth the effort here (unless you actually want to do something with the errors), here's a pretty complete example of using it:

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double) {
  def convert = {
    if (x == 1.0) throw new ConversionException(this, "x is 1.0. BAD!")
    else ConvertedPoint(x, y)
  }
}
case class ConvertedPoint(x: Double, y: Double)
class ConversionException(p: Point, msg: String) extends Exception(msg: String)


val points = List(Point(0,0), Point(1, 0), Point(2,0))

val results = points.map { p =>
  try {
    Left(p.convert)
  } catch {
    case e : ConversionException => Right(e)
  }
}

val (convertedPoints, errors) = results.partition { _.isLeft }

println("Converted points: " + convertedPoints.map(_.left.get).mkString(","))
println("Failed points: " + errors.map( _.right.get).mkString(","))
```

Comment: You stole my answer, but +1 for explaining it better :-) Welcome to SO.

Comment: Agreed - your answer was 100% correct (and an inspiration), but I think adding more detail justified another answer instead of just a comment. :)

Answer (score 17):

Interesting that I had a lot of trouble explaining the advantages of using `scala.util.control.Exception` over `try`/`catch`, and then I start to see questions that make perfect examples out of them.

Here:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
List(1, 23, 5, 2, 0, 3, 2) flatMap (x => catching(classOf[Exception]) opt (10 / x))
```

Your own code would look like this:

```
val points: Seq[Point] = ...
val convertedPoints: Seq[ConvertedPoint] = points.flatMap(
  p => handling(classOf[Exception]) by { ex =>
    logger.error("Could not convert", ex); None
  } apply Some(p.convert)
)
```

Or, if you refactor it:

```
val exceptionLogger = handling(classOf[Exception]) by { ex =>
    logger.error("Could not convert", ex); None
}
val convertedPoints: Seq[ConvertedPoint] = points.flatMap(p => exceptionLogger(Some(p.convert)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you want a flatMap. Here is an example, should see how it can fit :-)

```
List(1,2,3,4).flatMap(x => if (x > 2) Some(x) else None)
```

The above would use side-effect logging (printing or putting in something mutable -- if this is done, make sure the evaluation is forced!). To get around the side-effects and caveats, the mapping function could just be of `Point -> Either[CovertedPoint,Exception]` and then the results can be separated with `Seq.partition` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.10` you could use [`Try`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) to catch exceptions with [`flatMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatten[B](implicittoIterableOnce:A=%3Escala.collection.IterableOnce[B]):CC[B]) to get rid of these and starting `Scala 2.13` couple `Try` with [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) to log exceptions:

```
List("34", "a", "1", "3", "1l")
  .flatMap(x => Try(x.toInt).tap(_.failed.foreach(println)).toOption)
// java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
// java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1l"
// res0: List[Int] = List(34, 1, 3)
```

This:

- `map`s each element to an `Int` (our example of a code generating an exception) safe guarded by wrapping it in a [`Try`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/Try.html). This will produce a `Try[Int]` which is either a `Failure(NumberFormatException)` or a `Success(12)`.
- These `Try`s are `tap`ped to `print` (or log) the error for the `Failure`s. [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) applies a side effect (in this case some logging) on any value while returning the original value, so the returned value of `tap` is the element it's applied on, i.e. the unmodified `Try`.
- We then transform the `Try`s into `Option`s (`Success(12)` becomes `Some(12)` and `Failure(NumberFormatException)` becomes `None`) in order to apply a [`flatMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatten[B](implicittoIterableOnce:A=%3Escala.collection.IterableOnce[B]):CC[B]) which get rids of `None`s (`Failure`s) and extract values (`12` from `Some(12)` (`Success(12)`)).

---

Before `Scala 2.13`, an equivalent version without `tap` could be:

```
List("34", "a", "1", "3", "1l")
  .flatMap(x =>
    (Try(x.toInt) match {
      case f @ Failure(e) => {
        println(e)
        f
      }
      case s => s
    }).toOption
  )
```